# MySQL join select on two different database tables

Tags: mysql

Beginner here. I want to join two tables that resides in two different databases. 
Let's say:

```
Database 1 name is: a_database
Database 2 name is: b_database
```

a_database table name is: coupons 
and columns are: `id|coupon|created_at`
b_database table name is: partner_company_clients 
and columns are: `id|phone|coupon_id|created_at`

The query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM b_database.partner_company_clients pcc
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, coupon from a_database.coupons) mac on 
mac.id=pcc.coupon_id
WHERE pcc.partner_company_id=1 
AND pcc.deleted_at IS NOT NULL;
```

This works perfectly fine. But I do not want to pull everything from b_database.partner_company_clients table. Only the phone number column. 
If I remove the * and specify the column names it throws an error. I can't say why.

The select query becomes:

```
SELECT id, phone 
    FROM b_database.partner_company_clients pcc
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id, coupon from a_database.coupons) mac on 
    mac.id=pcc.coupon_id
    WHERE pcc.partner_company_id=1 
    AND pcc.deleted_at IS NOT NULL;
```

Error:

> Error: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: probably `SELECT pcc.id, phone .......`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query involves 2 id columns one from inner query and second from `partner_company_clients` so using `select id` it isn't clear enough which id column you want so use alias before the column name or use complete db and table name before columns

```
SELECT mac.id, pcc.phone 
....
```

or

```
SELECT mac.id, b_database.partner_company_clients.phone 
....
```